VS often loses Docker connection
I enjoy using Docker in VS because the GUI is pretty easy for me to understand. I can see Containers listed in VS, and then open up my code files from the Container drop down. So that when I make code changes and save the code, these code changes are reflected in the Docker container. I don't have to run like a copy or build command in Terminal.
The annoying part is sometimes VS seemingly loses this Docker connection. For example today I woke up and made a code change and tried to save my file. Got an error, it can't save the file. And then when I try to open the file through the Containers dropdown, Files is just stuck on a spinning wheel and doesn't actually show the files.
When this has happened in the past I have usually just bumbled around, deleted my current connection, made a new key, connected with that key, etc, and then hoped that it would randomly work (which it sometimes did after fumbling around for 30 mins). But obviously this is a huge impediment to my software dev work so I am looking for solutions, thanks.
